# android sdk not opening shows error

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

My sdk manager is not opening.When I open the android sdk manager, a cmd-like screen just briefly flashes on for half a second then disappears.

when I ran android.bat I got this
[android.bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2DbD.png)

My java is running fine (`java -version` gives `1.8.0_60`); then why am I getting this error?

Also eclipse shows this error also:

> `DDMS files not found: C:\Users\john\New folder (2)\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe C:\Users\john\New
>   folder (2)\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\hprof-conv.exe`

Comment: Eclipse? I'd highly recommend you to switch to Android Studio. Eclipse is dated and a headache for Android devs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1 :**

Go to [sdk-folder]/tools folder (For me it was C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\tools).

**Step 2 :**

Open the file android.bat in notepad by right clicking on it and selecting Edit from the context menu.

**Step 3 :**

Find the line in the file that says java_exe.

**Step 4:**

Now edit the “set java_exe=” line to

set java_exe="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"

Here “C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe” is the path where the java.exe file for the JRE is installed. You should check your Java executable location and change the line accordingly.

Now save the file and close it.  To test it out, in Eclipse go to Window > Android SDK Manager.

link : http://techathlon.com/fix-android-sdk-manager-failing-open-android-development-tools-bundle/

Comment: I had to set the path without using double quotes. now its working.Thanks.  What all packages are necessary to be downloaded through sdk manager for developing apps?

Comment: but you gotta be switching to android studio asap

Comment: presently have downloaded Eclipse. Can I also install Android studio

Comment: yup..here http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio, If you use android studio, you'll know it. and start your hatred towards eclipse. Eclipse is awesome...but not for developing android apps